# Ruby on rails No method error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into the infamous No Method Error. I've worked my way through a number of examples here on STOF but I can't see an error in my code that stands out. I've checked that rake routes matches what I think should be happening and the paths provided from using resources in the routes.db file seem to be correct. I know I'm missing some small detail but I can't for the life of me see it now. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Error Screenshot]

My Controller code:

```
class GenevarecordsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @genevarecords = GenevaRecord.all.page(params[:page]).per(5)
  end

  def new
    @genevarecord = GenevaRecord.new
  end

end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'genevarecords#index'

  resources :genevarecords

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a naming discrepency between your model and your controller / routes.
your model is `GenevaRecord`, underscored makes it `geneva_record`. However your controller only has a single capital letter at the beginning: `Geneverecords` which underscored would be `genevarecords`. Therefore when you pass your model to the form it tries to use a controller / routes helpers with the same naming format as the model, which would be `geneva_records_controller` ie. `GenevaRecordsController`.

What you need to do is match your controller and routes to the same naming format as your model:

```
class GenevaRecordsController < ApplicationController
  #...
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #...
  resources :geneva_records
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take `Did you mean?` section seriously,

Anyway, if you closely look at ruby syntax following is the representation for the class name,

`AbcDef` and equivalent snake case is `abc_def`

In your case,

Your model is named as `GenevaRecord` but your controller is `GenevarecordsController`

change it to `GenevaRecordsController`, also you need to match it's equivalent snake case in routes...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'geneva_records#index'

  resources :geneva_records

end
```

So, when you pass `@genevarecord` to the form it is initialized as `GenevaRecord.new` and searches for `geneva_records_path` which is undefined because you have defined it as `genevarecords_path` which doesn't match you `model` (resources)..

Hope it helps in understanding..

Comment: And `root 'genevarecords#index'` too.

Comment: Endlessly editing your answer to use similar wording and examples as an already provided answer isn't really a community spirited way to go about helping people...

Comment: well...it was hardly less than a minute's difference between the two answers..it was not intentional, I wanted to provide explanation as why is it so...

Comment: @JohnHayes-Reed, ohh it's your answer, I honestly read it now when you commented..and yes I agree, it should not have this much editing but I do it as something strikes my mind...